# PHP CSV file import does not import data if there's empty value

Tags: php, html, file, csv, import

I have this piece of code here and it doesn't import data if there's a comma in front of the row. It means an empty value in that column but my code doesn't recognize it and therefore doesn't import any data at all. 
Any ideas how can I fix that?
Thanks in advance!

```
    <?php
include "config.php";

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO norse5_proov (osakond, soetusaasta, it_number, tooteruhm, mudeli_nimetus, sn, riigivara_nr, inventaari_nr, maja, ruum, vastutaja, markus, kasutajanimi) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[10])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[11])."',
                    '".addslashes($_SESSION['user'])."'
                ) 
            ") or die(mysql_error()); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 

    header('Location:insert.php?success=1'); die; 

} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
if ($data[0]) {
```

to

```
 if (!empty($data)) {
```

Basically, what it is doing at the moment is checking if there is data in the first column, and if not it is ignoring the row, if you change it to the suggested, it will check if there is data in the whole row, and if there is then it will import it, otherwise it will skip.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a do while loop if you HAVE TO check your condition first, use a normal while loop instead. That way you dont have to check for your Data at all!

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")) 
{  
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO norse5_proov (osakond, soetusaasta, it_number, tooteruhm, mudeli_nimetus, sn, riigivara_nr, inventaari_nr, maja, ruum, vastutaja, markus, kasutajanimi) VALUES 
      ( 
      '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
      '".addslashes($data[1])."',
      '".addslashes($data[2])."',
      '".addslashes($data[3])."',
      '".addslashes($data[4])."',
      '".addslashes($data[5])."',
      '".addslashes($data[6])."',
      '".addslashes($data[7])."',
      '".addslashes($data[8])."',
      '".addslashes($data[9])."',
      '".addslashes($data[10])."',
      '".addslashes($data[11])."',
      '".addslashes($_SESSION['user'])."'
      ) 
    ") or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```